# Станное поведение LTRIM Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Столкнулся со странным поведением  LTRIM, функция удаляет лишние символы, см. пример ниже:

```
    select S.CODE_SUBJECT, LTRIM(S.PHONE_NUMBER,'+375'), LTRIM(980337778899,'980')
            from shema.table S
    where s.phone_number = '+375337778899' 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    CS789885    7778899 337778899

    Oracle 11.2    
    PHONE_NUMBER VARCHAR2 (4000 BYTE)
    NLS_CHARACTERSET AL32UTF8   
    NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET AL16UTF16   
    NLS_LANGUAGE RUSSIAN
```

В чем может быть проблема, кодировка, какие-то особенности работы LTRIM?

Comment: Что-то она ещё даже мало у вас удаляет, если почитать описание функции: https://oracleplsql.ru/ltrim-function.html

Answer (score 2):

Функция `LTRIM` работает в точности как и описано в [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/LTRIM.html#GUID-81B3D53C-0BBC-4485-B057-C8012CD6E40F):

> LTRIM removes from the left end of char all of the characters contained in set. [...]
>   Oracle Database begins scanning char from its first character and removes all characters that appear in set until reaching a character not in set and then returns the result.

В последовательнисти `[+375337778899]` будут удалены все символы слева, которые  входят в набор символов `[+375]`. Проверка идёт слева направо, и при первом несовпадени - `8`, остаток будет возвращён как результат - `[8899]`. Проверено на 11.2.0.1 и 19.0.0.0:

```sql
select ltrim (str, '+375') "result" from (
    select cast ('+375337778899' as varchar2 (16 byte)) str from dual);

result          
----------------
8899
```

Хорошей альтернативой `LTRIM` для задачи как в вопросе будет:

```sql
select regexp_replace (str, '\+375') "result" from (
    select cast ('+375337778899' as varchar2 (16 byte)) str from dual);

result          
----------------
337778899
```

Answer (score 0):

TRIM работает посимвольно, и соответственно последовательность символов 37533 воспринималась как 3753 - 3 (последняя тройка начало новой последовательности).
Пример:

```
select LTRIM('+3754','+375'), LTRIM('+3753','+375') from dual;
select LTRIM('+3754','+375'), LTRIM('+2752','+275') from dual;
select LTRIM('+3755','+375'), LTRIM('+37522','+3752') from dual;
```

Для себя перешел на REGEXP_SUBSTR, как более простой вариант можно использовать просто SUBSTR